# MySQL cannot recognize variable on file option

Tags: macos, mysql, mysql5, mysqld-safe

I'm using MySQL 5.6 on Mac OS X 10.8 and trying to configure mysql to log genreral_log into a file. However, it always throws an error when I start it.

Here is the `.my.cnf` file looks like (located at my home directory):

```
[mysqld]
general_log=/var/tmp/mysql/mysqld.log
log_error = /var/tmp/mysql/mysqld.error.log

[mysql]
log_error = /var/tmp/mysql/mysqld.error.log
#general_log_file = /var/tmp/mysql/mysqld.log
#auto-rehash
```

Whenever I fire up the mysql client on my terminal, it throws error like this:

```
mysql: unknown variable 'log_error=/var/tmp/mysql/mysqld.error.log'
```

And no matter I changed it to log-error, I still got that error. If I comment out the log_error line in [mysql] session it works fine.

Also, when I start `mysqld_safe` (at `/usr/local/mysql/bin`), it just recognizes the `log_error` variable but cannot recognize `general_log`. However, unlike `mysql`, `mysqld_safe` didn't give me any error.

Could you help me on this hairy bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option [log-error is a server option (mysqld)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-error).

It is recognized in `/etc/my.cnf` under the `[mysqld]` group.

That option does not exist for the [mysql client program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) and would not be understood under the `[mysql]` group header.

[Click Here to see all the options for the mysql client program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html).

The reason `log-error` works under the `[mysqld_safe]` group header? Any option mysqld_safe does not understand gets passed to `[mysqld]`.

The mysql client program cannot reroute the destination file of `log-error`. You must change it in `my.cnf` and restart. It will have no effect on `[mysqld]` group header in `.my.cnf` because `log-error` is not a dynamic variable.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql` client tool does not recognize the `log_error` option, and you should not attempt to use it.